# Pyplot: Cmap(index) -> color function

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Suppose I have the following:

```
data_mats = [ ... ]

# pseudo code
cmap = plt.(...).get_cmap('magma', low=0, high=len(data_mats))

for i in range(0,len(data_mats)):

    # pseudo code
    color = cmap(i)

    mat = data_mats[i]
    plt.plot(mat[:,1],mat[:,2], color=color)
```

How do I fill in the lines of pseudo code:

```
# lines of pseudo code
cmap = plt.(...).get_cmap('magma', low=0, high=len(data_mats))

color = cmap(i)
```

Using pyplot?

(why all the dense examples on matplotlib's website, rather than some code specs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 10
file_ct = 100

cmap = plt.cm.magma
color = cmap(float(i+1) / float(file_ct))
```

Comment: Is this additional information for your question?  Is this what solved your question? What is this?  At least add enough text to tell what this is.

Comment: @zero298 all of the above.  The documentation was complex, but the solution was trivial